# Can an asp:Button with Visible=False be submitted by a malicious user?

Tags: asp.net, security, button

Such a button is not rendered to the browser, so is there any way a malicious user would be able to trigger the action defined by the invisible button?  e.g. with a JavaScript call to `WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions`?  Would ASP.NET accept a POST that appeared to be triggered by this button, even though it wasn't rendered?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer **yes**.

It is always up to you (the developer) to ensure data received from user input (in this case a post) is valid. Having said that the asp.net framework will do a lot of verification for you, such as "suspicious looking post values".

It is possible to construct a post to a web endpoint, even if the page you display does not have a submit button.

**Edit**

This would be an example of [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) and is generally not a best practice. Asp.Net "submit" buttons modify a hidden form field called `__EVENTTARGET`. The asp.net handlers will inspect this field when determining a button click "event". This value can be spoofed if the attacker knew the name of the event target.

Hiding/showing UI elements are good for improving the user experience, but you should always validate (on the server) user input before performing any business actions.

Comment: Sure, anybody can POST anything they want.  What I was getting at (and didn't spell out, so I've updated the question) is would ASP.NET allow such a POST?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it would, if it's not rendered it shouldn't accept the postback.  .net uses hidden fields on the page to know which controls were on the page and can verify that during postback, so it knows what triggered the post back.  if the control was not there to begin with it shouldn't accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is definitely possible. ASP.NET accepts all POST values for controls defined on the page, visible or not. Beware too of i.e. textfields that are set to "read-only". Don't use `readonlyControl.Text` after the post, and trust that it has the same value as it had the last time you set it.

Take a look at what is posted when you perform a submit with ASP.NET with i.e. Chrome Developer tools, Fiddler, etc, and you should be able to figure out how to add your own value to an "invisible" text field.